# How to store random MySQL query for later use?

Tags: php, mysql, session

```
$user_name = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$database = "xxx";
$server = "xxx";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);

$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

$randWordDesc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($randWordDesc);

if(isset($_POST['new'])){

$unaltered = $db_field['word'];

$noA = str_replace("a", "b", $unaltered);


}

if (isset($_POST['edit'])){

global $noA;
$noR = str_replace("r", "c", $unaltered);


}

?>


<form action="http://xxx" method="post" ><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="edit current" name = "edit" id="gobutton">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="submit" value="new" name = "new" id="gobutton">
</form>
```

The code I have now will pull up a new word if the 'new' button is selected and replace the 'a''s with 'b''s. I want the 'edit' button to take the exact same word just pulled up and replace the 'r''s with 'c''s. However, as the code is now, the edit button will either pull up a new word or not pull up anything at all.

How could I get the edit button to edit the query that the 'new' button pulled up? I'm not sure how I could store it by the id, but all the columns have an id number, if that helps. Also I know that "SELECT * FROM words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1" is really bad form, but that's an issue I want to tackle after this problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're trying to hammer a nail in with a screwdriver. This should be done with JavaScript, not PHP. Use javascript interact with the user, building a list of changes to be applied to the database, then send the list to the server to be applied using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As the first query returns only one result, you could take the primary key column data of the resulting row and store it in a hidden input element on the page.  When you use the edit button, you would then pass the hidden input field value which can be used to pull the same record as you pulled with the most recent get new word function call.

Consider something like the following:

```
<form action="http://xxx" method="post" ><br><br>
<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $db_field['primary_key']; ?> name="record_id">
<input type="submit" value="edit current" name = "edit" id="gobutton">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="submit" value="new" name = "new" id="gobutton">
</form>
```

The id will be passed with your post, which you can then check for and use in a select query to get the record. Just be sure to be careful with data handling.  Consider updating to a current API (mysql~ functions are deprecated) and [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: i used your code (adjusting for my column names), but still when i hit the edit button it brings up a new record. any ideas?

Comment: You need to check for the POST data in PHP and include logic to handle it in the query. For instance, `if(isset($_POST['record_id'])) { $query = "SELECT * FROM words WHERE your_primary_key = ".$_POST['record_id']; }` from there, you can run the query, or if the POST data is not set, grab a random one like before.

Comment: wouldn't `if(isset($_POST['edit']))` work instead? should i check to see if the edit button has been pressed?

Comment: For the conditional, either may work for your intent. However, semantically I would prefer to separate the two such that the presence of a `record_id` value indicates that a specific row is to be pulled, and the presence of the `edit` value indicates how the retrieved row (regardless of whether it is specific or random) is manipulated. But of course, this is simply semantics.  The important part is that you've stored the value of the `primary key` so it may be used _within_ the conditional.